# how does my web browser resolve Domain Names?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, dns

I'm developing a network application which should be capable of contact DNS servers.

I was wondering what would be the best way to do it. And browsers came to my mind.

For example, how Firefox or Chrome resolve the Domain names i put in the URL bar?

I mean, i type http://www.google.com, how does it know that has to make a TCP request to the IP 209.85.195.104?

Thanks!

Comment: I've read around that DNS resolution is made by your ISP, but I don't know how much this is true and don't remember where I read it, sorry.

Comment: Yes, in fact, in my resolv.conf the first 4 nameservers (from 5) belongs to my ISP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the simplest scenario, browsers would use a function such as `gethostbyname()` to resolve names to addresses. However, this function is not always implemented in such a way that's convenient for a browser (it usually blocks until it gets an answer).

Browsers today are starting to use ["DNS prefetch"](http://www.google.com/search?q=dns+prefetch), where the browser will send DNS requests directly to a DNS server as the page is loading, to resolve addresses before the user clicks on the next link. That way, the user doesn't have to wait for name resolution when they click, and the browsing experience appears faster.

Comment: Example in Python: `import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname_ex('www.example.com'))`

Answer (score 1):

Web browser send request to DNS server. Server send list of associate addresses (if domain name record do have, several IP addresses - example is cnn.com with several IPv4 and IPv6 addresses).I am not sure if this addresses store browser or Operating systems but if browser use first address and don t get answer he will use another address from list. I read somewhere that it waits max 30 seconds until he use another address from list.